# How can i echo input data fields in an file_get_contents html template?

Tags: php, html, email, templates, encoding

I have this send_mail.php file. I'm trying to echo some fields that are inserted in a form and i can't with echo function. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

$date = $_POST['date'];
$full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
$biz_name = $_POST['biz_name'];
$activity = $_POST['activity'];
$afm = $_POST['afm'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$fax = $_POST['fax'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['website'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$discount = $_POST['discount'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['payment_amount'];
$seller_name = $_POST['seller_name'];


$to = $email;
$subject = "Welcome to our site!";


$htmlContent = file_get_contents("email_template.html");

// Set content-type header for sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// Send email
if(mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers)):
    $successMsg = 'Mail sending successful.';
else:
    $errorMsg = 'Oops! Something went wrong.';
endif;
?>
```

And my email_template.html looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to our site</title>
<head/>
    <body>
         <h1> Welcome <?php echo $full_name; ?> </h1>
         ...
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm new in web development so be gentle! :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I´ve just learned how to answer like simple text, my first answer was totally "coded".

Well, i suggest you learn codeigniter, it´s not the best for sure, but it´s the easiest on my view, and nowadays the most famous is laravel.

Nothing is easy for beginners anyway, but before starting studing any framework, look for understand php and php oo first.

See´ya! :)

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents()` doesn't parse the file as php. So one option would be to do something like this:

```
ob_start();
include('email_template.html');
$htmlContent = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

When you use `include()` it assumes you are running php code. Then we use an output buffer to capture the contents.

This way all variables are still available, otherwise you need to setup a whole template engine, in that case I would use an existing one like Twig.

Answer (score 1):

Edit template and mark variables by symbols or special names than replace real vars:
email_template.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to our site</title>
<head/>
    <body>
         <h1> Welcome --full_name-- </h1>
         ...
    </body>
</html>
```

php :

```
<?php
$htmlContent = file_get_contents("email_template.html");
$htmlContent = str_replace("--full_name--",$_POST['full_name'],$htmlContent);
```

Answer (score -1):

How are both files connected? Are you using ajax?

Look, if you´re using ajax, just return `$full_name`, and print it with jquery or javascript. (I believe you didn't this, but if you do...)

Otherwise, if you just posted and redirected to `send_mail.php`, just use echo on this same page, just like:

```
// Send email
if (mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers)):
     echo = 'Mail sending successful.';
else :
    echo = 'Oops! Something went wrong.';
endif ;
```

A third way I can suggest to you, is using `$_SESSION`.
On `send_mail.php` start a session with:

```
session_start();
//and declare
$_SESSION["full_name "]= $fullname;
```

Then you'll have this variable enabled for any page, while this user is on your site, and you just have to echo this way

```
echo $_SESSION['full_name'];
```

When you feel a little improved, I suggest you learn a php framework, that helps a lot. Good luck!

Comment: Nuh i'm just using html form which redirects to send_mail.php. 
Any suggestions on php frameworks to begin with?